# Connect to AWS Lightsail via ssh as Plesk domain's system user

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-lightsail

I have spent a whole day finding a solution this: I need to connect to the `/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld` via ssh, but can't do so with the ubuntu user as  those folders are not owned by `root`, but by the Plesk domain's system user?

I have tried so many things including

```
chmod 600 key.pem
ssh -i key.pem -T ubuntu@ip
```

which is the solution I found most and seemed to be working for many users, but it still all ended in `Permission denied (publickey)`.

This is so frustrating and I'be very happy to get guided here. Thanks so much for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Simple if you are using Lightsail terminal in browser i just typed root and everything worked grear it gave me an error first but was able to access the folder via ssh.